# worklight console v5.0.6 - enable authorized access to worklight server console

Tags: console, ibm-mobilefirst

I successfully install worklight server console v5.0.6 on liberty profile.

When I browse to http://{host}:9080/worklight/console. I immediately gain access to worklight console without any authentication.

It is harmful to the system when everyone can access to worklight console. In addition, it is very easy for mobile users to know worklight console URL as long as they know worklight server IP address from application setting on mobile device.

Is there anyway that I can limit this access to only authorized users only ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add Worklight Console protection. By default only to 1 user, but you can also connect to an LDAP server if you plan on giving access to multiple users...

See these topics:

- [Protecting Worklight Console](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/r_protecting_ibm_worklight_console.html)
- [worklight server authentication with Ldap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16662048/worklight-server-authentication-with-ldap)