# MobileFirst Server on Liberty Profile - LDAP authentication

Tags: ldap, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

I want to be able to log into mobilefirst console on my MobileFirst v6.3 Server which is running on a Liberty Profile using accounts from an LDAP repository.

I have edited my server.xml with the following LDAP Registry and LTPA configuration:

```
    <ldapRegistry id="AD_Example" realm="WASLTPARealm"
              host="example.com" port="389" ignoreCase="true"
              baseDN="dc=example,dc=com,dc=ar"
              bindDN="cn=binduser,cn=Users,dc=example,dc=com,dc=ar"
              bindPassword="ThisIsAnExample"
              ldapType="Microsoft Active Directory">

      <activedFilters userFilter="sAMAccountName=%v"
                       userIdMap="user:sAMAccountName">
      </activedFilters>

      <group name="worklightadmingroup">
          <member name="user1"/>
      </group>
      <group name="worklightdeployergroup">
          <member name="user1"/>
      </group>
      <group name="worklightmonitorgroup"/>
      <group name="worklightoperator"/>

</ldapRegistry>

<ltpa keysFileName="ltpa.keys" keysPassword="WebAS" expiration="120"/>
```

I took some info from the following places:

- ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/docs/v630/mobilefirst_platform_foundation_doc.pdf (Page 127)
- [worklight server authentication with Ldap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16662048/worklight-server-authentication-with-ldap)

But I can't seem to get this running. There is also going to be a DataPower integration scenario, but I need to test the LDAP connection first and I thought this might be the best approach. Any suggestions?

EDIT: [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8M9Q8HH0t0ofnUyeWk4b1dOS1NhRk92R3JGV0F5UHB2LTJoODNWT0RxYkJqMldRamxRbTg&authuser=0) you can take a look at the full logs (Console, Messages and ffdc). There is an "LDAPConnection" exception, but I can't understand the info it is giving to me.

Comment: So the question is, what's failing? you did not supply any error message nor your messages.log

Comment: User/Password incorrect. Sorry, I thought that was implied. Let me search for log entries.

Comment: Full messages.log please.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8M9Q8HH0t0ob3VlSmZzZTUxbFU&authuser=0

Comment: Make the file publically available (currently requires permission).

Comment: Done. Please, check now.

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded logging into worklightconsole by using a user in a LDAP registry (in my case an OpenLDAP, not a Microsoft Active Directory). What I find strange is that you are specifying **groups** as `<ldapRegistry>` children, shouldn't your groups be defined in your LDAP registry (and not in the server.xml) ? 
And then you can use the group **activedFilters**

```
<activedFilters
    userFilter="(&(sAMAccountName=%v)(objectcategory=user))"
    groupFilter="(&amp;(cn=%v)(objectcategory=group))" 
    userIdMap="user:sAMAccountName" 
    groupIdMap="*:cn" 
    groupMemberIdMap="memberOf:member" >
</activedFilters>
```

given in example [there](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_sec_ldap.html?lang=en) (there is a part on Microsoft Active Directory Server, of course you'll have to adapt to your case).

Also according to this [doc](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_feature_ldapRegistry-3.0.html?lang=en) (in **Feature configuration elements** click on ldapRegistry; you'll have all the attributes and children nodes that can be used), `<ldapRegistry>` doesn't seem to possess `<group>` child.

Comment: Hi Rick, just got those <group> elements out of the ldapRegistry element. Still the same result.

Comment: Yes, of course: https://drive.google.com/a/ayi-asociados.com/folderview?id=0B8M9Q8HH0t0ofnUyeWk4b1dOS1NhRk92R3JGV0F5UHB2LTJoODNWT0RxYkJqMldRamxRbTg&usp=drive_web

Comment: 1- I suppose that the password for apmovil1 is "TXZvQhCxzM4s" ?

Comment: 2- I suppose that in your LDAP at cuyanas.com.ar:389 you have defined the following groups: worklightadmingroup, worklightdeployergroup, worklightmonitorgroup, worklightoperator, appcentergroup

3- I think that you can remove the 4 groups defined after `<ltpa keysFileName="ltpa.keys" keysPassword="WebAS" expiration="120"/>`

Comment: Hi Rick. 1) No. That was wrong. I have already corrected it but it is still failing. Due to security reasons, I am not allowed to give you the correct one. 2) We do not have those groups in our LDAP server. From what you say, should we create them? 3) Ok, I will.

Answer (score 0):

The following LDAP exception is emitted : javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 775, v1db1

data 775 means that your user account (apmovil1) is locked. You must ask the LDAP administrator to unlock your user and then use the right password in the server.xml file since it is probable it was locked due to too many connection attempts with a wrong password.

Comment: Hi Bruno, user in fact is not blocked, just checked it within the Active Directory. Also, DataPower is able to authenticate that user on a Debug service we made available in the appliance.